# How can i trigger a GPU Crash

Tags: c++, gpu, directx, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

Sometimes we can trigger a "CPU Crash" with code like:

`*(int*)0=1234;`

Correspondingly, any simple code can trigger a "GPU Crash" (may need some DirectX interface)?

Why I need this is because I want to learn about Unreal's(UE4/UE5) GPU crash processing flow.
Any code with UE is expected.

THX

Answer (score 2):

It is very difficult to crash a modern GPU with decent drivers. Generally they will run until task completion. If the task is extremely large or takes a very long time, the OS will assume they have simply stopped responding. After this occurs, there are a few options:

- Crash: Very rare
- Reset the driver: This will reset the DirectX state and crash
  whatever program is using it (unless it is checking for that, but
  that seems like a waste)
- Abort the operation: This is a feature on
  more modern hardware and drivers, but they can simply stop the
  program.
- Run uninterrupted: This occurs only if the GPU is in use by NOTHING else.

Do some heavy calculation with no end (fractals) and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks a million! I will try as you say.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please mark as answered with the check mark if you consider the question completed.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a 'Timeout Device Recovery' (TDR) which is very similar to a GPU crash.

Using a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt running as admin:

```
dxcap -forcetdr
```

> Keep in mind this triggers a TDR for *all* running applications.